# Strange IE11 behavior with "Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'"

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, create-react-app

I have some trouble with my project in IE11 (It's react project, I use create-react-app prod build). It works fine in other browsers and in IE11 too, except if I click precise link to one route in IE11 (other routes work), it throws an error "Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'". I added 'babel-polyfill' but problem still exists, but if I, for example, not just load page, but reload it then too and then click that link, or when I load directly that link page it works fine.

I don't use 'includes' in my code, suppose it is used in some library, among those I use.

May be someone know, why it not work properly after loading page and after reloading only.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be handled separately from the rest of babel through [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-array-includes) plugin.

`includes` is a Javascript function that determines whether an item exists in an array, and it is not available in Internet Explorer. See docs/chart below. (Apparently it isn't part of babel by default because of some difficulty identifying whether a variable is an array. There are issues around this going back 2+ years in the babel repos.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Part of the browser compatibility chart from those docs:

[image]

Comment: McGuireV10, thank you for explaining. It was helpful and solved the issue.

Comment: If this answered your question you may want to mark the question as answered and upvote it.

Comment: how would the plugin you linked be correctly added to create-react-app's babel config? thank you!

Comment: This plugin seems to have some major pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

McGuireV10's answer is great if you can control your javascript compilation process, however including a shim might be faster.

In my create-react-app project using react-select v2 i was hitting a few of these errors, and so included [air-bnb's bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/airbnb-js-shims):

`yarn add airbnb-js-shims`

and then added this single line to my code:

`import 'airbnb-js-shims';`

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add below function in top of the all imports.

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
        value: function (searchElement, fromIndex) {

            if (this == null) {
                throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
            }

            // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
            var o = Object(this);

            // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
            var len = o.length >>> 0;

            // 3. If len is 0, return false.
            if (len === 0) {
                return false;
            }

            // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
            //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
            var n = fromIndex | 0;

            // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
            //  a. Let k be n.
            // 6. Else n < 0,
            //  a. Let k be len + n.
            //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
            var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

            function sameValueZero(x, y) {
                return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
            }

            // 7. Repeat, while k < len
            while (k < len) {
                // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
                // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
                if (sameValueZero(o[k], searchElement)) {
                    return true;
                }
                // c. Increase k by 1. 
                k++;
            }

            // 8. Return false
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```